# Any adjectives for the noun 'Renaissance'?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I have a blog titled 'Renaissance' which means revival of art and literature. I was keen on slightly changing the title of the blog by adding a proper adjective to the noun 'renaissance' but I could hardly find any poetic or catchy appropriate adjectives for the word on the web.

I presume there are not many adjectives for the same. Can you please suggest me some?

Comment: Isn't creative writing usually more clever than just "i want to put an adjective in front of this word?" Can you be more specific in what you want to *convey*?

Comment: Make one up. Use it. It will be in the dictionary next time you look.

Comment: Like @tenfour, I would ask what you're trying to say with that adjective? Because without a direction, I can suggest "Obsequious Rennaisance", "Olfactory Renaissance" or "Tiny Purple Rennaisance" as adjectives that can work great with your noun. You're asking for a word without giving us the definition of that word.

Comment: "Myopic renaissance", "mediocre renaissance", "abortive renaissance" "not much of a renaissance" ... // Also, "renaissance" is not restricted to art and lit.

Comment: [https://www.findwords.net/?query=Renaissance&find=a](https://www.findwords.net/?query=Renaissance&find=a)

Answer (score 4):

**[Renaissance](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Renaissance#Adjective)** itself can be used as an adjective:

> Renaissance (Adjective; not comparable)
>   Of, or relating to the Renaissance.
>   Of, or relating to the style of art or architecture of the Renaissance.

Comment: Yes, you are right but all through my blog I use it within the context of a noun. :( So I am actually looking for an adj that can describe Renaissance as a noun.

Comment: @VeeKay: I think your position there is a bit silly. The word *Renaissance* is by definition the correct adjective for the specific C14 cultural phenomenon. If your blog is not in fact about that historical context, perhaps you should amend your question to clarify what exactly you're writing about.

Comment: +1 In academic articles, *Renaissance* is very often used as an adjective. It is by all means acceptable, and there is no reasonable alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not referring to THE Renaissance, you could try **Renaissance Reincarnated**. This might appear too clever, but it might fit your need for something catchy. It literally means "rebirth reborn".